# Unicode characters in VBA dictionary

Tags: vba

I would like to use VBA dictionary to store key/value pairs in my macro.

There is a possibility that some of the characters are non English.

Can we store Unicode characters as keys in VBA dictionary , are there restrictions/ limitations ?

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Comment: True , will do that ..

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if there is a problem you should be able to use something like `CreateObject("System.Collections.Hashtable")` to get a .Net hashtable in VBA. I've used the arraylists in `System.Collection` in VBA with no problem. My guess is that a .Net container will be more likely to be Unicode friendly than an older VBScript object.

Comment: dictionary  does not support Unicode characters  , may be have to try System.Collections.Hashtable

Comment: And why not use builtin VBA Collection class? Have you tried it?